# Reading a File with Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, xss

I have a text file that contains a list of regexp's which I regularly use to clean html files according:

**list.txt**

```
<p[^>]*>|<p>
<\/?(font|span)[^>]*>|
<\/u>\s*<u>|
<\/u>\s*<i>\s*<u>|<i>
```

if each line consisted of the form **"#{a}|#{b}"**, what would be the simplest way to both read and convert this file into the array:

```
[
  [ /<p[^>]*>/, '<p>' ],
  [ /<\/?(font|span)[^>]*>/, '' ],
  [ /<\/u>\s*<u>/, '' ],
  [ /<\/u>\s*<i>\s*<u>/, '<i>' ]
]
```

Comment: Umm, I just wrote you a code which would work for | as well.
Try that.

Comment: Wrote another code that would work for "!"
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
result = File.foreach("list.txt").collect do |line|
  *search, replace = line.strip.split("|", -1)
  [Regexp.new(search.join("|")), replace]
end
```

Or if your separator does not occur in the regexes and replacements:

```
result = File.foreach("list.txt").collect do |line|
  search, replace = line.strip.split("!", -1)
  [Regexp.new(search), replace]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `#{b}` part will never contain a `|`, I get the following:

```
File.open(filename,"r").collect
  { |s|
    x = s.rindex('|');
    [ Regexp.new(s[0..x]), s[x+1..-1].chop ]
  }
```

Otherwise, you'll probably have to replace `s.rindex('|')` with something more complicated.